# Como passar variáveis de ambiente para o Maven em linha de comando?

Tags: maven

Quero passar valores de variáveis de ambiente para o Maven via linha de comando.
Como fazer?

Tentativas:

- `mvn liquibase:update -Dliquibase.url=$DB_URL`: o Maven executa, mas o valor não é passado
- `mvn liquibase:update -Dliquibase.url=${DB_URL}`: o Maven executa, mas o valor não é passado
- `mvn liquibase:update -Dliquibase.url=${env.DB_URL}`: erro de bash:

> -bash: -Dliquibase.url=${env.DB_URL}: bad substitution

Comment: O primeiro e segundo métodos são equivalentes, e não consigo imaginar o motivo de não terem funcionado

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado acho que está certo mesmo. O problema é na hora do liquibase se conectar com o banco. Ele não está passando o user. Achei que era problema da chamada mas não é. Vou responder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falha minha.

O comando `mvn liquibase:update -Dliquibase.url=$DB_URL` funciona.
Achei que não funcionava pois o Liquibase não estava recebendo os parâmetros, mas é por um outro problema.